# Select colon value by using linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to select values of one colon has where condition(it becomes from values of the idlist). Then this values will be added the fiyatlist.Code I tried is below.

How to do it?

```
public ActionResult Create(string UrunId, List<String> idlist)
{
       List<String> fiyatList = new List<string>();
       if (idlist != null)
       {
           ViewBag.abc = idlist;
           int i;

           for(i=0;i<idlist.Count();i++)
           {
               var sorgu = from a in db.Urunlers where a.UrunId == Int32.Parse(idlist[i]) select new { a.UrunFiyat};
               fiyatList.Add(sorgu.ToString());

           }
           ViewBag.fiyat = fiyatList;
        }

        return View();
}
```

But thing returns is query not value

**UrunList View**

```
@foreach (BillApplication.Models.Urunler con in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="urunsec" type="checkbox" name="cbList" value="@con.UrunId.ToString()" onchange="ClickMe(this)" />

                </td>
                <td>@con.UrunId</td>
                <td>@con.UrunAdi</td>
                <td><div id="=fiyatdiv"> @con.UrunFiyat </div></td>
                <td>@con.AltkategoriId</td>
                <td colspan="4"></td>
            </tr>

        }
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Gönder" name="Command" />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

**Create View**

```
 <td>
                <textarea id="txt_urunler" rows="2" cols="20" style="border-style:inset; width:150px; border-width:0.2em; border-color:gainsboro">

                    @if (@ViewBag.abc != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var i in ViewBag.abc)
                        {
                            @i
                        }
                    }
                </textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea id="txt_fiyat" rows="2" cols="20" style="border-style:inset; width:150px; border-width:0.2em; border-color:gainsboro">
                    @if (@ViewBag.fiyat != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var i in ViewBag.fiyat)
                        {
                            @i
                        }
                    }
                </textarea>
            </td>
```

**Create Action**

```
public ActionResult Create(string UrunId, List<String> idlist, List<String> fiyatList)
    {

       if (idlist != null)
        {
            ViewBag.abc = idlist;

        }
       if (fiyatList != null)
       {
           ViewBag.fiyat = fiyatList;
       }

           return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Faturalar mReg, string Command, string txt_cari)
    {
        if (Command == "hesapla") { }
        else if (Command == "Ürün Seç") { return RedirectToAction("UrunList"); }


        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should not be creating extra objects, in this example (sorgu)**

Here you are creating sorgu which is not being used to do any further calculations.

```
for(i = 0; i < idlist.Count(); i++)
{ 
     fiyatList.Add(db.Urunlers.Where(a => a.UrunId == int.Parse(idlist[i])
                     .FirstOrDefault()).ToString()); 
}
```

Create a lamda for clean code. Its your choice though.

You should be using Model instead of ViewBag too.

Comment: I'm confused.Can you give an example code by using model

Comment: Refer link below. 


http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller

Comment: when I use this code,İt gives errors like ..Urunlers cannot be used like  a method  @Muks

Comment: @ZehraOzdogan have you tried the latest code from here. 

Is your query resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach(var item in idlist)
{
     int reqInt;
     if(!int.TryParse(item.Trim(), out reqInt)
     {
         throw new Exception("Invalid Value");
     }
     var sorgu = (from a in db.Urunlers 
                 where a.UrunId == reqInt 
                 select a.UrunFiyat).FirstOrDefault();
     fiyatList.Add(sorgu.ToString());
}
```

OR

```
var finalList = db.Urunlers.Where(x => idlist.Select(int.Parse).ToList().Contains(x.UrunId)).Select(v => v.UrunFiyat).ToList();
```

Comment: if idlist have one element code is working.But one more code gives an error:**An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code**

Comment: @ZehraOzdogan Is `idlist[i]` contain integers?

Comment: yes,it represents id values of products.I convert string because I'm showing in view

Comment: @ZehraOzdogan I have edited my post, test it again please

Comment: I edited your code.Firstly finalList should be fiyatList. Then when I try 2 selections.it works when idlist has one element,but if it has one more element,gives error An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code like first comment

Comment: If can you help,I will so please

Comment: @ZehraOzdogan Can you show me contents of `idlist`?

Comment: Contents of idlist is values of checkboxlist has id of products.
<code>
public ActionResult UrunList(FormCollection frm)
        {
            string str_idList = frm["cbList"].ToString();
            TempData["idList"] = str_idList;
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Fatura", new { idList = str_idList });
        }<code>

Comment: @ZehraOzdogan This code is not helpful form me because I don't know whats is `RedirectToAction` and `frm["cbList"]`.

Comment: @ZehraOzdogan I want to make sure that each `idlist[i]` contains integers. I mean its value can be convert into `int`. If it contains some characters or alphabets then `int.Parse` will throw exception

Comment: @ZehraOzdogan I have update loop (first answer), please try it and let me know

Comment: @ZehraOzdogan Did you try first answer, i update it? On which line exception thrown?

Comment: Yes,I've tried .But same error.İt works for only one element

Comment: On which line exception thrown?

Comment: var sorgu = (from a in db.Urunlers ...this line.Infact after idlist 've seen in textarea there is spaces.I quess I need to trim function